# Integer Array inside if/Elif Statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have the following code, which appends lines of a text file to respective lists if they begin with a certain number.

Is there a way I can and use a numerical array and loop to save some lines of code? The number just needs to stop at 9.

Thank you.

```
for number in f:
if number.startswith('1'):
        startsw1.append(number)
elif number.startswith('2'):
        startsw2.append(number)
elif number.startswith('3'):
        startsw3.append(number)
elif number.startswith('4'):
        startsw4.append(number)
elif number.startswith('5'):
        startsw5.append(number)
elif number.startswith('6'):
    startsw6.append(number)
elif number.startswith('7'):
    startsw7.append(number)
elif number.startswith('8'):
        startsw8.append(number)
elif number.startswith('9'):
    startsw9.append(number)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do

```
some_num_dict = {
    '1': startw1,
    '2': startw2,
    '3': startw3,
    '4': startw4,
    '5': startw5,
    '6': startw6,
    '7': startw7,
    '8': startw8,
    '9': startw9
}
for number in f:
    some_num_dict[number[0]].append(number)
```

Of course, I'm assuming `number` is some numerical string object.

EDIT: Just like how the others mention. If your just doing 9 lists that are similar to each other, it may be better to make a list of the lists...

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a single list, with nested lists with the index indicating the starting digit.

```
startsw = [[] for i in range(0,11)]

f = ['122','423','42341','635'] 
for number in f:
    startsw[int(number[0])].append(number)
```

Output:

```
[[], ['122'], [], [], ['423', '42341'], [], ['635'], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to fill your lists in the global stack, you can use `globals()` to grab references to your lists and then just append to them:

```
for number in f:
    globals()["startsw" + number[0]].append(number)
```

This assumes you've already created `startsw1`, `startsw2`, `startsw3` ... `startsw9` lists in the global namespace and that all elements in `f` are strings and have their first character as a number.

However, it's much better to just use a dedicated `dict` to store your number lists:

```
 starts_dict = {i+1: [] for i in range(9)}
 for number in f:
     starts_dict[number[0]].append(number)
```

Comment: Polluting globals is a no-no.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - the OP already polluted the globals with creation of different lists - this just appends to them, doesn't put anything new there.

Comment: I like that second option better. Too bad I've maxed out my votes, or else I'd have +1'd.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you requested to use a list to hold your lists, but I think that using a dictionary will be more natural. The way that you use the code will end up being identical, but if for some reason in the future you need to support more than just indexing by integers then you won't have to change anything.

A default dictionary is the most natural solution.

```
from collections import defaultdict
starts_with = defaultdict(list)
for number in f:
    # Probably should have some error handling in case the first
    # character cannot be converted to an int.
    starts_with[int(number[0])].append(number)
```

The nice thing here is that you don't have to preallocate your `starts_with` object like you would have to with a `list`. You can even simply store the keys as strings (i.e. `'1'`) instead of ints if you wish.

Please note that this assumes that you will use this `starts_with` dictionary instead of nine different list variables `startsw1`..`startsw9`, which in the long run will end up being easier to maintain.